# Modify Stored Procedure Post Deployment

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, visual-studio-2013, sql-server-2012

Is there a way to modify a stored procedure in post deployment scripts?

I am trying to modify stored procedures in a Visual Studio 2013 SQL Server Database Project and SQL Server Express 2012. I know that I can manually modify the stored procedure in the build, but depending on what branch of our application I'm working on, I need the stored procedures to change.

I've tried a number of ways to write scripts but always wind up with SQL80001 or SQL72007 around the syntax `ALTER PROCEDURE` or `CREATE PROCEDURE`.  When I attempt to recreate the procedure, I do Drop it first.

The following script is being linked to Script.PostDeployment.sql.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spCreateTemplate]
(
     @name varchar(250),
     @dataSourceID nvarchar(1)
)
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @id uniqueidentifier

SELECT @id = NEWID()
INSERT TemplateInfo
(
  ID,
  Name,
  DataModeID,
  DataSourceID,
  StartDepth,
  EndDepth,
  StartDateTime,
  EndDateTime,
  Increment,
  IsActive,
  IsRealTime,
  IsLogarithmic,
  CreatedBy,
  CreatedUTCDate,
  ModifiedBy,
  ModifiedUTCDate
)
VALUES
(
    @id,
    @name,
    1,
    @dataSourceID,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    1,
    0,
    1,
    0,
    SUSER_SNAME(),
    GETUTCDATE(),
    SUSER_SNAME(),
    GETUTCDATE()
)

SELECT @id
END
```

Comment: Have you verified that the SQL file itself has it's build action set to 'None'. There have been known issues with similar bugs when this isn't set properly.

Comment: The script does not look complete. I dont see an END for example. Please check if something did not go missing when pasting the script into question.

Comment: I think your stored procedure is missing BEGIN...END. Because it consists of multiple lines the BEGIN...END is required

Comment: Sorry, that was an editing error on my part.  The BEGIN and END are included in the code but the same errors are received.  Dillie, the Build Action is set to none.  I have also verified I am using the latest SSDT.

Comment: Are you missing a `GO` before and after the script?

Answer (score 3):

I have finally been able to resolve this issue. In order to alter the procedure, I had to run the stored procedure sp_executesql and pass it the script to create the stored procedure. Here is an example of what I did:

```
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

    DECLARE @sqlCmd nvarchar (4000)
    IF EXISTS(select * FROM sys.procedures where name = <spName>
    begin             
        drop procedure <spName>
        SELECT @sqlCmd = 'CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[<spName>]
             (<@variables datatype>)
             AS
             BEGIN
                 SET NOCOUNT ON;
                 DECLARE @id uniqueidentifier

                 SELECT @id = NEWID()
                 INSERT
                 <tablename>(<columns>)
                 VALUES
                 (<values>)

                 SELECT @ID
             END'
             EXEC sp_executesql @sqlCmd        
       END
   else
   begin
        SELECT @sqlCmd = 'CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[<spName>]
        (<@variables datatype>)
        AS
        BEGIN
             SET NOCOUNT ON;
             DECLARE @id uniqueidentifier

             SELECT @id = NEWID()
             INSERT
             <tablename>(<columns>)
             VALUES
             (<values>)

             SELECT @ID
         END'
         EXEC sp_executesql @sqlCmd       
END
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm also having this issue in post-deployment.

scenario:
2 files

post-deployment code

```
:r "file1.sql"
:r "file2.sql"
```

what I did to fix this is to ADD the following in every files (e.g file1.sql and fil12.sql)

```
...<afterENDline>
<line>
<line>
GO
<line>
```

I think the reason why this occur is because the post-deployment copies all the lines like `:r "files1.sql"` into a single `.sql` file.

therefore, I think you can also fix it by doing this way:

```
:r "file1.sql" GO
:r "file2.sql" GO
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: this was a day saver!!, thaks!